# Google Maps park borders

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to display park borders on Google Maps? I've been able to style parks to be purple using the following style:

```
{
    featureType: 'poi.park',
    elementType: 'geometry.fill',
    stylers: [{color: '#aa44aa'}]
}
```

[image]

And have tried the following to enable the border, but it didn't work.

```
{
    featureType: 'poi.park',
    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
    stylers: [{color: '#000000'}]
}
```

Full jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/acbj49uq/1/).

The Style Reference for Google Maps is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference).

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Parks</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example creates circles on the map, representing populations in North
      // America.


      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 37.180240, lng: -121.434949},

          styles: [
          {
              featureType: 'poi.park',
              elementType: 'geometry.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#aa44aa'}]
          }/*,
          {
                featureType: 'poi.park',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#000000'}]
          },*/
          ]
        });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, an API doesn't expose features borders. There is a really old feature request in Google issue tracker, however, it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953

Feel free to add a star in the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.